# GhostScript: Ps2Pdf comes out blank

Tags: python, pdf, tkinter, ghostscript, converters

I'm trying to convert a .ps file to .pdf.

In my code I'm creating a rectangle with "Python" write inside of it.

If I run .ps in a window (tkinter window) it comes great but when I convert to pdf and try to open the pdf it comes out blank.

Here's my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import subprocess

# Create the root window
root = tk.Tk()

# Create the canvas widget
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=200, height=100)
canvas.pack()

# Create a rectangle on the canvas
new_rectangle = canvas.create_rectangle(25, 25, 150, 75, fill="blue")

# Write the word "Python" inside the rectangle
canvas.create_text(62, 50, text="Python", fill="white")

# Save the canvas as a postscript file
canvas.postscript(file="rectangle.ps", colormode='color')

# Run the tkinter event loop
# root.mainloop()


# Convert .ps file to .pdf
process = subprocess.Popen(["ps2pdf", "post_script.ps", "result.pdf"], shell=True)
```

Comment: Are you certain you are using the Ghostscript ps2pdf shell script, and not something else ? There are an awful lot of 'ps2pdf' scripts/binaries around. If you are certain, then I suggest you try taking the PostScript file and running ps2pdf on it from the command shell. FInally; instead of running the script (which is stupidly simple) just do "gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o out.pdf posts_script.ps" in the command shell. If that fails you can open a bug report at bugs.ghostscript.com. Don't forget to attach the example file and command line

Answer (score 0):

there seem to be inaccuracies in your code:

here:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(["ps2pdf", "post_script.ps", "result.pdf"], shell=True)
```

**post_script.ps** is previously named **rectangle.ps** and shall be therefore renamed to rectangle.ps.

then: your `root.mainloop()` is in the code example wrongly commented

and finally:

you shall call `canvas.update()` before saving the canvas as a postscript file.

(or you can dedicate special button to generate pdf --> then it is perhaps not necessary to call canvas.update() )